# $E_1+E_2$ is open if both open?

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

if $X$ be a norm linear space and $E_1,E_2\subseteq X$ then  $E_1+E_2=\{x+y:x\in E_1,y\in E_2\}$ is open if both open? is open if one is open and another is closed? closed if both are closed?

I just know that in real line with usual topology sum of two closed set is not closed, and sum of two open set is open.

Comment: Well, $x \mapsto x+y$ is a homeomorphism, and $E_1+E_2$ is the union of sets $E_1+y$. So if $E_1$ is open, then ..?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan under homeomorphism open set goes to open set and closed goes to closed set